# Copy specific file first and the copy all in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The following is what I have for my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:4.6.0

WORKDIR /src

COPY node_modules/ /src/node_modules

COPY . /src/

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

I wanted to make it efficient such that node modules are copied only when there's any change in the directory. Otherwise, I want only the source files are copied into the image.
Would this work as intended?

Comment: *"Would this work as intended?"* -- Have you tried?

Comment: Of course I tried, but there's no way for me to tell whether the node_modules copied once, twice, or none. My question is the efficiency of this approach.

Comment: The commands in the `Dockerfile` are executed only once, when the image is built. I wouldn't worry about their efficiency. Anyway, I think your commands copy the `node_directory` twice. If you want to have the content of `node_modules` in the Docker image always up to date you should not copy it into the image. Use [`VOLUME`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) and the [`-v`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only) command line option to map the host directory into the `/src/node_modules` directory of the image on every run.

Comment: @axiac " I think your commands copy the node_directory twice" <== this is what I wanted to confirm. So, I should devise another way to copy node_modules and the rest of the code separately... I can't use `-v` since the built image will be deployed to the dev. testing environment.

Comment: Blast from the past but 1) it will get copied twice 2) this is a bad approach because if somebody is building with a mac, you could end up with dependencies build for a mac and then copied to a linux OS which will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

This will copy twice. Docker cache looks at the current command and previous layer. If something has changed in the Docker context for the current command it will run. It does not use a partial cache to run.

Comment: thanks for commenting. is there any way to guarantee to copy `node_modules` only once? all i could think of at the moment is to list `node_modules` in `.dockerignore` file, but I wonder if there's any alternatives.

Comment: The only way to guarantee would be to copy node_modules and then copy everything else manually instead of COPY . /src/

So you would have individual COPY commands for everything in your directory and run the COPY for node_modules first. It is more verbose and creates more layers. But it is the only way to ensure node_modules is copied once and only once.